Node Module not found CLI
I've been writing my own CLI tool to bundle my JS projects automatically, but when trying to run it, it cannot find the config, even though there is one. Trying to run it in other directories works without an problem.
Command ran:
allpack

CLI code:
#!/usr/bin/env node
const commander = require("commander");

commander
  .version("1.0.0", "-v, --version")
  .usage("[OPTIONS]...")
  .option("-m, --mode <value>", "Overwriting mode.")
  .option("-c  --config <value>", "Overwriting config file.")
  .parse(process.argv);

const mode = commander.opts().mode;
const configPath = commander.opts().config || "./allpack.config.js";

const webpack = require("webpack");
const fs = require("fs-extra");
const path = require("path");
const config = require(configPath);
const ignoreList = config.ignore || [];

const buildBundle = (dir, outputDir, subdirName) => {
  // Create a webpack configuration for the specific directory
  const webpackConfig = {
    mode: mode || config.mode || "development",
    entry: path.join(dir, "index.js"),
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(outputDir),
      filename: subdirName + ".bundle.js",
    },
  };

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    webpack(webpackConfig, (err, stats) => {
      if (err) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve(stats);
      }
    });
  });
};

const main = async () => {
  const pbSrcDir = config.src
    ? path.join(process.cwd(), config.src)
    : path.join(process.cwd(), "pbSrc");
  if (fs.existsSync(pbSrcDir)) {
    if (fs.existsSync(config.outputDir)) {
      fs.removeSync(config.outputDir);
      fs.mkdirSync(config.outputDir);
    } else {
      fs.mkdirSync(config.outputDir);
    }
    const subdirs = fs.readdirSync(pbSrcDir);

    for (const subdir of subdirs) {
      console.log("Found:", subdir);
      const subdirPath = path.join(pbSrcDir, subdir);
      console.log(subdirPath);
      if (
        fs.lstatSync(subdirPath).isDirectory() &&
        !ignoreList.includes(subdir)
      ) {
        try {
          await buildBundle(subdirPath, config.outputDir, subdir);
        } catch (err) {
          console.error("======Webpack Error======");
          console.error(err);
          console.error("==========Stats==========");
          console.error("Directory:", pbSrcDir);
          console.error("Output Directory:", config.outputDir);
          console.error("Config:", JSON.stringify(config));
          console.error("=========================");
        }
      }
    }
  } else {
    console.error("======Allpack Error======");
    console.error("Src directory not found.");
    console.error("==========Stats==========");
    console.error("Directory:", pbSrcDir);
    console.error("Output Directory:", config.outputDir);
    console.error("Config:", JSON.stringify(config));
    console.error("=========================");
  }
};

main().catch((err) => console.error(err));

It should find the config in the path
allpack.config.js

When running
node -e "require('./allpack.config.js')"

it finds it without problems.

Found out the solution.
I tried to access the module IN the package, not the directory it's being used in. Simple fix with path.join() and process.cwd()
